# Proving multiplication of Eigenfunctions is zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given I have the following boundary value problem:

$$\ddot{x}+ q(t)\cdot x=\lambda x,$$

$$x(a)=x(b)=0.$$
Each solution of the above is called eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Prove that given two eigenfunctions $x_1,x_2$ with different eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ the following holds true:

$$\int_{a}^{b} x_1x_2dx=0.$$

I have tried partial integration but this leads to just another integral that I cannot solve. I might not be able to solve it because I do not understand the interpretation of the above integral.

Can somebody help or point me into the right direction?

Comment: This is not true, what is true is that $\int_{a}^{b}x_{m}(t)x_{n}(t)e^{\int{q}(t)dt}dt=0$

Comment: Are you sure that the given differential operator $L=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+q(t)\frac{d}{dt}$ is correct? $L$ isn't self adjoint! For $L=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+q(t)$ the statement is true, because $L$ is self adjoint.

Comment: You guys got me, added the integration limits and fixed the differential operator $L$ (there is no first derivative on the let hand side but the original function). But there is no mention of $e^{\int q((t)dt}$ in my assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with self-adjoint operators $A$ and eigen-pairs $(λ_k,v_k)$ with $λ_1\ne λ_2$ you consider
$$
λ_1\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=⟨Av_1,v_2⟩=⟨v_1,Av_2⟩=λ_2⟨v_1,v_2⟩
$$
where the equality of the first and last term is only possible if $⟨v_1,v_2⟩=0$.

Answer (score 1):

LutzL has given the second part of the answer. Firstly you have to show that $L$ is self adjoint with respect to
$$\langle \phi,\psi\rangle=\int_a^b \phi(x)\psi(x)dx$$
That's $L=L^{\dagger}$, consequently $\langle L\phi,\psi\rangle=\langle\phi,L\psi\rangle$. But for that you need more boundary conditions, I think.

Comment: Got it, thanks!